# cannot render a specific field using form_alter

Tags: forms

I am trying to theme my form using alter form.
I want to render a specific field with theme('ctools_collapsible', xxxx).
For now I can only results field but without their values, any help ?

```
   //What I want to render
    $collapsed_content = drupal_render($form['field_markets'][$language][$i]); 
    $form['field_markets'][$language][$i] = '';
    $form['field_markets'][$language][$i]['#markup'] = theme('ctools_collapsible', array('handle' => $collapsed_content, 'content' => 'here another content to display', 'collapsed' => TRUE));
```

I used this way to render the data in view mode (using hook process node), and It works fine, now I am trying to do same thing in edit mode.
The results of this, I can see fields but there are empty...

Comment: try this code
$form['field_markets'][$language]['#theme'] = array('ctools_collapsible');

Comment: Thanks,but I tried your solution before.
$form['field_markets'][$language][$i]['#theme'] = array('ctools_collapsible'); is only displaying the arrow without anything...
field_markets is actually a field collection item so I think I am missing something else